# Using ANTLR on IBM USS

Tags: java, antlr, cobol, mainframe, uss

I've tried to port Craig Schneiderwent's Cobol parser ([mapa](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/mapa)) under IBM z/OS USS.
It seems to function generally, but fails to parse the Cobol source.
See  [issue 104](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/mapa/issues/104) .
Craig assumes this could be a codepage translation issue. I've tried all his advices with no success.
The question is, which codepage understands ANTLR - UTF-8? Or something special?

Comment: I've reas through "issue 104", and have some questions. You're talking about "MVS files", and "OMVS files". I guess the Cobol code initially is in an MVS data set (MVS files, as you say). How exactly do you copy it to the USS file system?

Comment: Do you have a command line for how you are running ANTLR ?

Comment: I made some comments on the javac compiler errors in the mapa repo Issue #104. Check that you have the generate Visitor.java files. If so, check your classpath. I'm not sure if that is the problem, or you worked past that and are looking at the encoding for the char stream.